I'm trying to understand the behavior of having multiple viewports in libgdx as seems unpredictable
I have been fighting with placing two small viewports, the main one which uses the entire screen space, and a secondary with is just at top right (as the idea is to draw a FPS counter there)
The problem is that I can't understand how exactly it works, I have been talking with the AI, and after some changes the viewports just work.... But I need to understand why my first implementation doesn't work, as the AI answer is quite bad "Sometimes you just have to use manual viewport placing, because sometimes setScreenPosition may not work as expected"
The NOT working code:
public class TestViewportGame extends Game {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera mainCamera;
    private OrthographicCamera smallCamera;
    private Viewport mainViewport;
    private Viewport smallViewport;
    private ShapeDrawerHack shapeDrawerHack;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        // Main camera setup
        mainCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
        mainViewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), mainCamera);
        mainViewport.apply();
        mainCamera.position.set(mainViewport.getWorldWidth() / 2, mainViewport.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);
        mainCamera.update();

        // Small camera setup
        smallCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
        smallViewport = new FitViewport(200, 150, smallCamera);
        smallViewport.setScreenPosition(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 200, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 150);
        smallViewport.apply();
        smallCamera.position.set(smallViewport.getWorldWidth() / 2, smallViewport.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);
        smallCamera.update();

        // Initialize ShapeDrawer
        shapeDrawerHack = new ShapeDrawerHack(new ShapeDrawer(batch));
        shapeDrawerHack.load();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        ScreenUtils.clear(Color.BLACK);

        // Render main scene
        mainViewport.apply();
        mainCamera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(mainCamera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        // Draw main scene elements here
        batch.end();

        // Render small viewport
        smallViewport.apply();
        smallCamera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(smallCamera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        shapeDrawerHack.getShapeDrawer().filledRectangle(0, 0, smallViewport.getWorldWidth(), smallViewport.getWorldHeight(), Color.RED);
        batch.end();
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        mainViewport.update(width, height);
        smallViewport.update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        shapeDrawerHack.dispose();
    }
}

The working code:
public class TestGame extends Game {
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private OrthographicCamera mainCamera;
    private OrthographicCamera smallCamera;
    private Viewport mainViewport;
    private Viewport smallViewport;
    private ShapeDrawerHack shapeDrawerHack;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        batch = new SpriteBatch();

        // Main camera setup
        mainCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
        mainViewport = new FitViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight(), mainCamera);
        mainViewport.apply();
        mainCamera.position.set(mainViewport.getWorldWidth() / 2, mainViewport.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);
        mainCamera.update();

        // Small camera setup
        smallCamera = new OrthographicCamera();
        smallViewport = new FitViewport(200, 150, smallCamera);
        smallCamera.position.set(smallViewport.getWorldWidth() / 2, smallViewport.getWorldHeight() / 2, 0);
        smallCamera.update();

        // Initialize ShapeDrawer
        shapeDrawerHack = new ShapeDrawerHack(new ShapeDrawer(batch));
        shapeDrawerHack.load();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        ScreenUtils.clear(Color.BLACK);

        // Render main scene
        mainViewport.apply();
        mainCamera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(mainCamera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        // Draw main scene elements here
        batch.end();

        // Render small viewport
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(Gdx.graphics.getWidth() - 200, Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - 150, 200, 150);
        smallCamera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(smallCamera.combined);
        batch.begin();
        shapeDrawerHack.getShapeDrawer().filledRectangle(0, 0, smallViewport.getWorldWidth(), smallViewport.getWorldHeight(), Color.RED);
        batch.end();

        // Reset viewport to main camera
        Gdx.gl.glViewport(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        mainViewport.update(width, height);
        smallViewport.update(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        batch.dispose();
        shapeDrawerHack.dispose();
    }
}

Notice:

The only difference is the use of manual viewport positioning, instead of using the viewPort apply method
The only custom class is ShapeDrawerHack, which is just a wrapper around ShapeDrawer texture loading and disposal

